# Small world, spider's web, when lava conquers, does it give victory points at the end?

Tags: small-world

When using the Lava special power from the Spider's Web expansion, do spaces with lava count as 'occupied' to score victory points?  Or do they just count as a 'defense' until your next turn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for Lava state

> At the end of your turn, for each Mountain Region you occupy, you may
>   place 1 Lava Token in any Region adjacent to that Mountain Region
>   (excluding Regions protected by Special and Racial Powers). All tokens
>   in this Region are taken in hand by the defeated player and treated as
>   if the Region were conquered (except there is no loss of tokens). The
>   Region may not be entered by any other player until after the
>   beginning of your next turn. At the beginning of your next turn,
>   remove all Lava Tokens from the board and proceed as usual.

So the Lava tokens are not conquering the regions, they are simply treating the defending tokens as if they were conquered.  Therefore you would not score points for those regions.

Comment: OK, that's how I was leaning toward interpreting it, but wanted another to verify for me.  Thanks